# Should I keep with 2 views, or can I combine into 1?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, view

I currently have 2 views: `t_sdet_part` and `t_sdet_part_all`.  `t_sdet_part` is pulling data from view `table_mv`, along with creating rows that don't already exist in `table_mv`.  Then that data created is joined into another view to show all records (`t_sdet_part_all`).  Below is my current code:

```
-- view created: t_sdet_part
WITH v as (
      SELECT v.*
      FROM table_mv v
    )
SELECT d.s_date, ig.part_no, ig.i_group, l.s_level, ig.p_category,
       COALESCE(v.qty_ordered, 0) as qty_ordered
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT s_date FROM v) d CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT part_no, i_group, p_category FROM v) ig CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT '80' as s_level FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT '81' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT '95' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT '101' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT '100' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Late' FROM DUAL
     ) l LEFT JOIN
     v
     ON v.s_date = d.s_date AND v.part_no = ig.part_no AND
        v.i_group = ig.i_group AND v.s_level = l.s_level
ORDER BY s_date, part_no, i_group,
    DECODE(s_level, '80', 1, '81', 2, '95', 3, '101', 4, '100', 5, 'Late', 6)

-- view created t_sdet_part_all
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.s_date,
    t.part_no,
    t.i_group,
    t.s_level,
    t.p_category,
    t.qty_ordered,
    v.bucket,
    v.relief_amt,
    v.extreme_amt,
    v.curr_mth_note,
    v.carryover_note
FROM
    t_sdet_part t
    LEFT JOIN table_mv v ON t.s_date = v.s_date
                                              AND t.part_no = v.part_no
ORDER BY
    s_date,
    part_no,
    i_group,
    DECODE(s_level, '80', 1, '81', 2, '95', 3, '101', 4, '100', 5, 'Late', 6)
```

They are both pulling and joining data from `table_mv`. I'm trying to find a way (if it's even possible) to combine both of the below files so I only have to create 1 new view instead of 2.

Comment: You can *always* use a CTE to combine the queries.  There may be other approaches for simplifying the code as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I had tried that, but am not familiar with CTE's enough to make it work, so that's how I ended up with my current result.  I've still been trying to make it work, just keep getting lost in my own code and starting over.